# Ring Signatures: Why is the combination function easy to solve?

Tags: encryption

I'm reading Rivest's *How To Leak A Secret* and am on the part where they describe their signature scheme ("Generating a ring signature").

Why is computing $C_{k, v}(y_1, ..., y_r) = v$ easy? The computation seems to be "linear" or single-threaded, i.e. of the form $E_k(y_r \oplus E_k(y_{r-1} \oplus E_k(...E_k(y_1 \oplus v))))$. So let's say $r_i=s$ -- we require the value of $y_i$ to proceed with the computation (i.e. we can't continue to encrypt if we don't know its value), and so wouldn't we just be stuck trying all values of $y_i$ until we hit one that results in $v$ when the computation finishes?

Wikipedia also says that $C_{k, v}$ is trivially invertible given $r - 1$ parameters. I'm blanking out - why is this the case?

I did look at [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/wanted-simple-ring-signature-example) but I didn't understand the line

> Start again at 12 o'clock and calculate going counter-clockwise until you arrive at 6 o'clock.

How can you "go counter-clockwise" when all the computations counter-clockwise have inputs dependent on all previous computation? All of the XORs have the previous computation as input.

---

Sorry if I've made any gaffs, this is my first *Exchange question.

Comment: Does reading [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52608/48404) make it understandable?

Comment: I think there may be a bug in that OP @Ruben. For some pre-computed random value $v'$, the full formation of $v$ is: 

$$v = H(... \oplus H(y_s \oplus H(y_{s - 1} ...)))$$
$$ = H(... \oplus H(v'))$$

Following:

$$v' = y_s \oplus H(y_{s - 1} ...)$$

$$h = H(y_{s-1} ...)$$

$$v' = y_s \oplus h$$

$$y_s = v' \oplus h$$


which works. But OP is defines $h = H(y_s ...)$ - not $H(y_{s-1}...)$. So their full computation looks like:


$$v = H(... \oplus H(y_s \oplus H(y_{s} \oplus H(y_{s -1} ...))))$$

which doesn't match the algorithm RST describes (ring backtracks on $y_s$).

Comment: That's an amazing attention to detail there, have a vote. I'll edit the question to read $\mathcal{H}(y_{s-1})$. Could you confirm that I made the right edit? It's a real index madness.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have a potential solution, anyone care to confirm this? Let's take an example with 5 public keys (including ours). Let's assume our $s = 3$.

Let's borrow from that previous Stack Overflow post. Let's define a left var as

$$l = E(E(E(v \oplus y_1) \oplus y_2) \oplus y_3 )$$

and we know that

$$ z = r = E(E(l \oplus y_4) \oplus y_5))$$

Now let's start decrypting $z$:

$$D(z) = E(l \oplus y_4) \oplus y_5$$
$$D(z) \oplus y_5 = E(l \oplus y_4)$$
$$D(D(z) \oplus y_5) = l \oplus y_4$$
$$D(D(z) \oplus y_5) \oplus y_4 = l$$

We've solved for $l$! Solving for $y_s = y_3$ is easy now:

$$l = E(E(E(v \oplus y_1) \oplus y_2) \oplus y_3 )$$

$$D(l) = E(E(v \oplus y_1) \oplus y_2) \oplus y_3$$

$$D(l) \oplus E(E(v \oplus y_1) \oplus y_2) = y_3$$

And then we just do $g^{-1}(y_3)=x_3$, giving us our full signature.

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 1):

You can "go counter-clockwise" because XOR and symmetric encryption E are both invertible functions.

Specifically, you have an equation $C_{k,v}(y_1, ..., y_r) = v$.
You know only $s-th$ private key, right? so you can invert only $y_s$ (find $x_s$ so that $g_s(x_s) = y_s; here $g_i(x) means encryption of $x$ with  $i$-th public key).
So, by the algorithm, you choose just random $x_i$ for all $i \neq s$, and set $y_i = g_i(x_i)$. But it's not for $y_s$, which you will find from the equestion:
$$C_{k,v}(y_1, ..., y_r) = v.$$
Worth to note, that in this equasion you know all variables (all $y_i$, $v$, $k$) except $y_s$.
How you can solve it?
You understand that it's simple in a forward direction to evaluate the function $C_{k,v}(y_1, ..., y_r)$,
unless you comes to a position $s$, where you have:

$$
y_s \oplus E(y_{s-1} \oplus ...) = y_s \oplus V_1, 
$$
where $V_1$ is some easy calculated value.

Then, to find which value should the last expression equal, you need to evaluate that our equation ($C_{k,v}(y_1, ..., y_r) = v$) "from another end", or "counter clockwise".
We have:
$$E(y_r \oplus X_r) = v,$$
where $X_r$ stands for $E(y_{r-1} \oplus E(y_{r-2}...))$.
Could we find $X_r$? Sure, because XOR is invertible, and encryption $E$ is invertible too:
$$
X_r = E^{-1}(v) \oplus y_r.
$$
Then, having $X_r$, you could solve the next equation $E(y_{r-1} \oplus X_{r-1}) = X_r$ in the same way.
We repeat this "inverting of $C_{k,v}$" until we come to a position $s$.
Now, combining results of "clockwise" and "counter-clockwise" evaluations,
we have a fixed equation:
$$
E(y_s \oplus V_1) = X_s.
$$
Not worth to say that it's easy to solve.
When you find $y_s$, you will find $x_s$ by reverting $g_s$, thanks for you having the secret key.