# Mathematics behind the paper "how to leak a secret" for ring signature

Tags: signature, secret-sharing

I'm reading the paper ["How to Leak a Secret"](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/RST01.pdf) (Rivest, Shamir, Tauman; 2001).

On page 8/14, in chapter 3.4, the authors present the following "combining function":

$$C_{k,v}(y_1, y_2,\ldots,y_r) = E_k(y_r \oplus E_k(y_{r−1} \oplus E_k(y_{r−2} \oplus E_k(\ldots \oplus E_k(y_1 \oplus v)\ldots)))) .$$

Is there any explanation for why this function satisfies the second one of the three properties listed on the previous page:

> 2. Efficiently solvable for any single input: For each $s, 1 \leq s \leq r$, given a $b$-bit value $z$ and values for all inputs $y_i$ except $y_s$, it is possible to efficiently find a $b$-bit value for $y_s$ such that $C_{k,v}(y_1, y_2,\ldots,y_r) = z$.

A concrete example of how to solve it would be ideal.

Comment: please read my comment on the same question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61420/ring-signatures-why-is-the-combination-function-easy-to-solve/64668#64668, maybe it will help you

Answer (score 1):

From the paper, $E$ is a cipher, i.e., $E_k$ is a permutation. That is, given a secret key $k$, one can compute both the encryption $y=E_k(x)$ (for any $x$) and the decryption $x=E^{-1}_k(y)$ (for any $y$). Therefore, if you know $z$ and all but one $y_i$, you can pick a $v$ (which equals $z$ in the context of ring signature) and get the missing $y_s$ by computing the XOR of $s-1$ $E_k$ encryptions starting from "inside" of the $E(E(...))$ expression and $r-s$ $E_k^{-1}$ decryptions starting from "outside". For instance, if $r=3$ and $s=2$, then $y_2=E_k(y_1\oplus v)\oplus E^{-1}_k(E^{-1}_k(z)\oplus y_3)$.