# Ring Signature's "solve for y_s" step in Rivest et al.'s "How to leak a secret"

Tags: rsa, signature

I'm reading Rivest et al.'s "How to leak a secret", but I'm having a hard time understanding step 4 of the generation procedure. This could be because of my own lack of knowledge regarding operations on ring but the following: [image]

makes very little sense to me. How am I supposed to solve this equation? I've tried looking for examples and I stumbled upon [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/wanted-simple-ring-signature-example) other question, but sadly this only ended up confusing me even further, as I don't understand how that kind of construction could lead to the solution (again, likely caused by my lack of knowledge regarding ring operations).

Do I just "unroll" $C_{k, v}$ and invert the $E_k$s until I'm able to solve for $y_s$? Note that this is how the combining function is defined: [image]

Could anyone provide a complete example for this? Pointers to what is that I'm lacking are hugely appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
C_1 = E_k(v\oplus y_1) \\
C_2 = E_k(C_1\oplus y_2) \\
... \\ 
v = C_r = E_k(C_{r-1}\oplus y_r)$$
Since we know $y_1, ..., y_{s-1}, y_{s+1}, ... y_r$ and $v$:

1. get $C_{s-1}$ by encryption from $C_1 \to C_2 \to ... \to C_{s-1} $
2. get $C_{s} = E_k(C_{s-1} \oplus y_s)$ by decryption from $C_r (= v) \to C_{r-1} \to ... \to C_{s}$
3. decrypt $C_{s}$ to get $C_{s-1} \oplus y_{s}$.
4. Finally we get $y_s = (C_{s-1} \oplus y_s) \oplus C_{s-1}$.